# display into fixed html area

Tags: html, css

In my html I get 'response' from controller. Number of lines in the response varies (max is 3). 
What is the best way to 'reserve' 3 lines on my html page so the next div with 'SOMETHING' paragraph is not scrolled down by 'response' ?

```
<div class="row">
    <p ng-bind-html="response"></p>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <p>SOMETHING</p>
</div>
```

Comment: number of lines is *relative* to line width and screen width.     same line of text can be 3 lines on small screen.      This question has nothing to do with AngularJS,  but with CSS.    You should fix your field's width, and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS, fix the height occupied by your 3 rows and use `overflow` to scroll within that fixed height div.

[CSS Overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) might help you.

`.row-fixed-height {
    height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;
}`

and in HTML:

```
<div class="row-fixed-height">
  <p ng-bind-html="response"></p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the height of the lines varies based on font and font size, I would use line breaks to "reserve" the three lines. If you were to use for instance a fixed height on the `div` or `p`, it might jump around on a different browser that uses a different font.

**Live Demo:**

```css
#response {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <p id="response" ng-bind-html="response">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </p>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <p>SOMETHING</p>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/rspyho74/

Answer (score 1):

As [oori](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701473/display-into-fixed-html-area#comment53246260_32701473) pointed you, this is is about CSS, not Angular. The easiest way to fix the height to 3 lines is using the [`em`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-length) unit:

```css
.row{
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
p{
 float: left;
 margin: 0 5px;
 padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <p ng-bind-html="response"></p>
    <p ng-bind-html="response">Line 1</p>
    <p ng-bind-html="response">Line 1<br>Line 2</p>
    <p ng-bind-html="response">Line 1<br>Line 2<br>Line 3</p>
    <div style='clear: both;'></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <p>SOMETHING</p>
    <div style='clear: both;'></div> 
</div>
```

As you can see, the paragraph keeps its height no matter how many lines there are. If you remove the `height` property you can see the difference.

Comment: Why `ng-bind-html="response"` 4 times?

Comment: Hi, @AniketSinha. As I said in the last paragraph, it's to show how the `p` element can maintain its size despite the number of lines. If you remove the key property, `height`, all paragraphs adequate their height to the text. It's just to show the behavior of the blocks.